# Pass input data from Angular to NodeJS

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb

I am currently learning the MEAN stack and I'm wondering how I can pass data from the inputs in .html to my nodeJS app.js ?

Let's say I have a form :

register.component.html:

```
  <form>
    <input type="text" name="surname">
    <input type="text" name="name">
    <input type="text" name="username">
    <input type="password" name="password">
    <input type="submit" value="Register">
  </form>
```

And I would like that when it's submitted, it calls the register function :

resister.component.ts :

```
register(){
    this.http.post('http://localhost:3001/login/' // etc )

  }
```

So in my app.js :

```
app.post('/register', function(req, res){
    db.collection('users').insertOne({
        prenom : //inputs data,
        nom: //inputs data,
        email : //inputs data,
        password : //inputs data
    })
})
```

My question is : **How can I pass the data from the inputs in the .html TO the app.js ?
**

Thank you very much, I'm sorry if this question feels noob to most of you, but I am learning !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, your form should apply the two-way binding.

```
<form (ngSubmit)="register()">
    <input type="text" name="surname" [(ngModel)]="input.surname" />
    <input type="text" name="name" [(ngModel)]="input.name" />
    <input type="text" name="username" [(ngModel)]="input.username">
    <input type="password" name="password" [(ngModel)]="input.password" />
    <input type="submit" value="Register">
</form>
```

Alternative: Work with [Reactive form](https://angular.io/start/start-forms).

---

In the component, you should declare an object for the `input` (form).  Pass the object to the post and make sure that you need to `.subsribe()` to post the API request and get returned response for success/failure handling.

Meanwhile the API URL should be "/register" but not "/login" based on your NodeJS service.

```js
input: any = {
    surname: "",
    name: "",
    username: "",
    password: "",
};

register(){
    this.http.post('http://localhost:3001/register', this.input)
        .subscribe(
            next => {
                // TO-DO Success event
            },
            error => {
                // TO-DO Error event
            });
}
```

While if you work with Reactive form, you will require `FormBuilder` service and `FormGroup` instance (Not covering too much as the first link illustrates the flow to use it).

Reference: [Angular Post Request Example](https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2019/11/21/angular-http-post-request-examples)

---

Not a Node.JS developer, but your back-end service implementation should be:

```js
app.post('/register', function(req, res){
    db.collection('users').insertOne({
        prenom : req.body.surname,
        nom: req.body.surname,
        email : req.body.email,
        password : req.body.password
    })
})
```

to get the value from the request body.

And of course, your password should be encrypted as security best practice before saving the record into the database.

Comment: It looks promising actually, thanks a lot
Although, it doesn't add the data to "input", it just register some blank fields, 

Maybe because you can't use

this.http.post('http://localhost:3001/register', input)

But we have to use

this.http.post('http://localhost:3001/register', this.input)


Really sorry for the formatting, it doesn't work the same way a a post 

Comment: Yes, you are right, the declaration of a variable in the component needs to use `this` (`this.input`) to access the value. Unless when declaring the variable in the function scope then doesn't require `this`. Thanks for the correction.

Comment: You're welcome :)
So, it doesn't seem to fill the data into   input: any = {
    prenom: "",
    nom: "",
    email: "",
    password: "",
};

Comment: My bad. Should be `[(ngModel)]` (two-way binding) not `[ngModel]` (one-way binding). [Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ripfpo?file=src/app/app.component.html)